# Using One Hot Encodings

Tags: tensorflow2.0

Problem definition:

Implement the function below to take one label and the total number of classes   , and return the one hot encoding in a column wise matrix. Use tf.one_hot() to do this, and tf.reshape() to reshape your one hot tensor!

- tf.reshape(tensor, shape)

`enter code here`
def one_hot_matrix(label, depth=6):
"""
    Computes the one hot encoding for a single label
    
    Arguments:
label --  (int) Categorical labels
depth --  (int) Number of different classes that label can take
    
    Returns:
one_hot -- tf.Tensor A single-column matrix with the one hot encoding.
"""

```
# (approx. 1 line)
# one_hot = ...
# YOUR CODE STARTS HERE


# YOUR CODE ENDS HERE
return one_hot
```

`enter code here`

Answer (score 6):

when you take this one serious `"# (approx. 1 line)"`

```
 one_hot = tf.reshape(tf.one_hot(label,depth,axis = 0), [depth, ])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Since we need to create a single-column matrix, we need to define the shape using the depth(rows of matrix). The required shape is [depth,]

Usage: 
tf.reshape(tensor_object, shape)

tf.reshape documentation link: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape

Answer (score 0):

```
one_hot = tf.one_hot(label, depth, axis = 0)
one_hot = tf.reshape(one_hot, (-1,1))
```

Comment: Shape (-1,1) won't work. We need to specify the rows same as depth.

Answer (score 0):

```
one_hot = tf.reshape(tf.one_hot(label,depth,axis=0), (depth))
```